# Setting Kubernetes emptyDir volume size

Tags: kubernetes

I'm creating a ram based emptyDir volume for a pod.

```
 volumes:
  - name: ram-disk
    emptyDir:
      medium: "Memory"
```

Because this is a ram disk, I need to set the maximum size which it will take from the ram. Is there a parameter to set maximum size and minimum size?

Comment: For those of you who found this question via web search: This feature is still in beta as of Kubernetes v1.22. You must enable a feature gate to enable this feature. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/

Answer (score 12):

For kubernetes versions above 1.7.x, it's [possible to set the `sizeLimit` for an `EmptyDir`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) with the caveat that it has a feature gate. The default is set to true since 1.22 but it is still in beta stage.

Comment: Default size limit for {'medium': 'Memory"} emptyDir is 1/2 of the total RAM on the Kubernetes node. That is the default for any tmpfs mount on Linux. (So you are more likely to hit the memory limit for pod, since that is probably smaller than 1/2 of node's RAM.)

Comment: This link no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: No, at least not for now.

This is an open issue, see [13479](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13479). Since I don't know your use case, I suppose my only suggestion is to try and use `hostPath` as a workaround, see also the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) for more details.

Comment: My use case is to mount a ram disk for my pod that contains a server that is expected to do disk read and write operations quickly. I can create a ram disk at docker level but it requires privileged mode on docker. I think emptyDir with ram medium does the same thing but I need to specify the maximum size of that volume.

Answer (score 5):

Adding an example (extending @flyer' answer):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
...
spec:
  volumes:
    - emptyDir:
        sizeLimit: 1Gi
      name: log
```

Comment: You do not seem to use "medium: Memory" with that volume.

Comment: "medium" is relative, I would rather specify the size.

Comment: @Vishrant in this context medium refers not to something between high and low, but to the material used to back the volume, ie RAM is used instead of disk.

Comment: this does not work on 1.24
tested via `fallocate -l 10G gentoo_root.img` on a 1Gi size volume

Answer (score 4):

Since Kubernetes 1.20 there is the feature gate [SizeMemoryBackedVolumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) (currently alpha feature) which does exactly this.

> Enable kubelets to determine the size limit for memory-backed volumes (mainly emptyDir volumes).