# How do I limit container disk usage without evicting?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, resources, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

I'm trying to use Kubernetes on GKE (or EKS) to create Docker containers dynamically for each user and give users shell access to these containers and I want to be able to set a maximum limit on disk space that a container can use (or at least on one of the folders within each container) but I want to implement this in such a way that the pod isn't evicted if the size is exceeded. Instead ideally a user would get an error when trying to write more data to disk than the specified limit (e.g., `Disk quota exceeded`, etc).

I'd rather not have to use a Kubernetes volume that's backed by a gcePersistentDisk or an EBS volume to minimize the costs. Is there a way to achieve this with Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `emptyDir` volume on Kubernetes, which is a temporary disk attached to your pod, you can set a size for that.

See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565438/54929, this question is likely a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But unfortunately exceeding the `sizeLimit` of an `emptyDir` causes the pod to be evicted.

Comment: I think you're looking for a feature that doesn't exist. :) Also if you tried something and it didn't work, it should be part of your question, don't make us guess what you tried.

Comment: I do think that feature probably doesn't exist after all. The question clearly asks for a solution where the pod isn't evicted though. So perhaps the answer should've considered that it doesn't apply :)