# Can I define minimum size for emptyDir in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I created a pod with a volume mounted on it as `emptyDir`.

```
        - name: tmp
          emptyDir: {}
```

However the pod has only ~5GB of memory allocated to `tmp` directory. Is there a way I could predefine the tmp volume in such a way that I can get ~50GB memory allocated to it?

Note: I tried setting `sizeLimit` based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610763/setting-kubernetes-emptydir-volume-size) but it is to set the upper limit and not the lower limit for an emptyDir volume.

Also I prefer using ephemeral storage for this application rather than [persistent volumes.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Generic ephemeral volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/ephemeral-volumes/#generic-ephemeral-volumes) if you are looking for the behavior of ephemeral volume but features of PVC. This will allow you to specify the size of ephemeral volume you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am looking for something for older kubernetes version (1.19)